# Заживають чи загоюються (рани)?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, словосполучення

У [CУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/zazhyvaty):

> **ЗАЖИВАТИ** 1, ає, недок., ЗАЖИТИ, иве, док. *Загоюватися, виліковуватися, ставати здоровим.*
>
> //  *Затягуватися шкірою, зарубцьовуватися (про рану)*.
>
> **ЗАГОЮВАТИСЯ**, юється, недок., ЗАГОЇТИСЯ, оїться, док. *Переставати ятритися, боліти; заживати, виліковуватися.*

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/zaghojuvatysja)

Але, у [«Як ми говоримо» Антоненка-Давидовича](http://slovopedia.org.ua/34/53399/33254.html) знаходжу:

> **ЗАЖИВАТИ , ГОЇТИСЯ , ЗАГОЇТИСЯ
>   Заживати, гоїтися, загоїтися**
>          Дієсловом **заживати** часом користуються **не з його значенням**: «Два поранення ніби зажили», «Рани мої зажили». Але українська класична література й народне мовлення надавали дієслову **заживати** іншого значення: «Зажила вона собі ще того щасливого часу слави доброї панночки» (Ганна Барвінок); «Ой не знав козак, ой не знав Супрун, як славоньки зажити» (історична дума); «Годі тобі віку мого заживати» (з живих уст).
>          **Коли мовиться про рани й виразки, тоді треба вдаватись до дієслів гоїтися, загоюватися:**.

Отже, як правильно: **рани загоюються чи заживають?**

Answer (score 2):

Можна сказати як і "рана загоюються", так і "рана заживають". Ви праві, зідно до СУМу слово "заживати" може мати значення: "Поведінкою, працею і т. ін. заслуговувати, здобувати собі пошану, славу, честь, успіх, ставати відомим, популярним завдяки чому-небудь", однак як ви вже написали у самому питанні, воно ще й може мати значення: "Загоюватися, виліковуватися, ставати здоровим". Також приклади такого вживання із літератури: " Як тільки зажила рана, Левко Когут вирішив вивести своїх бойовиків на операцію. (І. Цюпа) ", "* Образно. Довго і боляче заживала рана її юного серця. (Я. Гримайло)", тощо (приклади взяті [звідси](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8)).

Також [словник синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) вказує, що "заживати" може бути синонімом до "загоюватися". Отож, можна вживати як одне, так і інше дієслово.